# Android programming. Passing a array from one activity to other

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

How do I pass an array between these two activities

Main ACtivity

```
package com.Rohit.intentpurchase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CheckBox c[] = new CheckBox[4];
int[] price = new int [] {20,50,60,80};
int sum = 0;
int num = 0;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    // Created reference for checkbox
    c[0] = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    c[1] = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    c[2] = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    c[3] = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    // even handling for button
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { 
                // on user checked particular box
                if(c[i].isChecked()) {
                    // Get certain box checked
                    name = c[i].getText().toString();
                    // Total of price
                    sum = sum + price[i];
                    // No.of items selected
                    num = num + 1;
                }
            // sending the data to second activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActiviy.class);
            // converted to in.putExtra(String name , string[] value)
            in.putExtra("name", name);
            in.putExtra("Price",sum);
            in.putExtra("Total",num);
            startActivity(in);

    }

        }
    });
}
```

}``

Second Activity
    package com.Rohit.intentpurchase;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActiviy extends Activity {
// created an array for Textbox
TextView t[] = new TextView[6];
int i,num,sum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_activiy);
    t[0] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t[1] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    t[2] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    t[3] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    t[4] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    t[5] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);

     for(int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {    
        // Get access to data from 1 activity
         Intent in = getIntent();
        // Get String array name from 1 activity
         String[] name = in.getStringArrayExtra("name");
        // got a problem here
        t[0].setText(name[i]);
    // no problem here 
        int total = in.getIntExtra("Total",num);
        int price = in.getIntExtra("Price",sum);

        t[4].setText(" TOTAL: "+ total);
        t[5].setText(" PRICE: "+ price); 
     }



}
}

Xml 
Files Main activity

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/CB1" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="@string/CB2" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:text="@string/CB3" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:text="@string/CB4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox4"
    android:text="@string/Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/Items" />
```

```
Second Activity XML
<!--
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".SecondActiviy" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/si" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/T2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/T3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/T4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/T5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="@string/price" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/Items" />

    </RelativeLayout> '`
    --->
```

These above are xml files by name mainactivity and second activity. Just to show enduser, how my application looks.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Are you trying to ask something?

Comment: I see a lot of code, but I have no idea of what you are trying to achieve and what is your problem.

Comment: dunno your culture, but where i grew up a question comes along with a question..

Comment: Error is null pointer.When im trying to execute my code. Im facing the null pointer exception. ITs happening in second activity, when im trying to access the following code.
    'Intent in = getIntent();
         // Get String array name from 1 activity
       String[] name = in.getStringArrayExtra("name");
         // got a problem here
         t[0].setText(name[i]);'
 Because im trying to call, String name from main activity. The rest of the xml code is my UI.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas Good that you see just code, but i even passed the comments on code where im facing error :).

Comment: @bofredo Neither i know anything about culture. But i know question comes along a question, that was heading of my topic. I guess in my culture , we read topic heading :)

Comment: Null pointer exception. I guess its been happening, when im trying to call. t[i].setText(name[i]);

Answer (score 2):

For passing, in your MAinactivity try something like

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent((getApplicationContext(), SecondActiviy.class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

And for receiveing in your SecondActivity

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Send a Bundle containing the data. Have a look at the documentation. [putIntegerArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putIntegerArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.Integer%3E%29) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

you want this ??

to pass from activity 1 :

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

To Read From Activity 2:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

in activity 1 :
List tempArrayList = new Arraylist();

```
tempArrayList.add(name);
tempArrayList.add(price);
tempArrayList.add(total);
```

now

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray(key, tempArrayList);
    Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
    i.putExtras(b);
```

in activity 2 :

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] array=b.getStringArray("tempArrayList");
```

Comment: Hey hussain.According to your answer. Im not passing any string values on put string array. As im trying to display the selected item of first activity checkbox in second ?

Comment: Ive already passed different, items. If u go to second activity. There is a problem when u trying to call t[i].setText(name[i]);. There im facing null pointer exception. Its workng , if im just trying to pass t[i].setText(name), its just executing last checked checkbox.

Comment: @B.rohitNare : see the edit , i'll have to check your very scenario , will answer then

Comment: Im not passing array list hussain. Im just passing arrays. Have you been through the code once ?

Comment: @B.rohitNare :can I have your layouts ??

Comment: Too big to send here, can i send u images

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

In the first activity you created an array of 4 indexes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

CheckBox c[] = new CheckBox[4]; //HERE!!
```

**low  bound c = 0 

  high bound c = 3;**

But, in the second activity you are trying to access 4 and 5 indexes because in the second activity the high bound of the array is 5

```
public class SecondActiviy extends Activity {
// created an array for Textbox
TextView t[] = new TextView[6];
```

**low  bound t = 0 

  high bound t = 5;**

```
  for(int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {    
        // Get access to data from 1 activity
         Intent in = getIntent();
        // Get String array name from 1 activity
         String[] name = in.getStringArrayExtra("name");
        // got a problem here
        t[0].setText(name[i]);
        // no problem here 
        int total = in.getIntExtra("Total",num);
        int price = in.getIntExtra("Price",sum);

        t[4].setText(" TOTAL: "+ total);
        t[5].setText(" PRICE: "+ price); 
     }
```

So, you cannot do This:

```
// got a problem here
t[0].setText(name[i]);
```

Because when `j = 4` or `j = 5`, it will trespass the **highest index** of the array "name".

Answer (score 0):

In the second activity you are not changing the value of index i, so it is always initialized to 0.